# Close the socket.io connection when user changes route in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

Socket.io closes the connection when user try to close the tab or window but it does not when user navigate to other route in same angular app, the disconnect event will not fire in that case.
server-side:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

the socket.disconnect() method will not work.

I am trying to use CanDisconnect routing guards but does not know how to use that to close the connection.

server side:

```
// dependencies
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//importing routes
var loginRouter = require('./routes/loginRoutes');
var chatRouter = require('./routes/chatRoutes');
app.use('/', loginRouter); // applying routes to the app
app.use('/', chatRouter); // applying routes to the app

// starting the server
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('server is listening on port '+PORT);
});

// socket.io ===================================

io_public = io.of('/public');  // namespace public
io_public.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        socket.username = username;
        socket.room = 'public'; //assign default public room
        socket.join(socket.room);

        socket.emit('server', 'you have connected to a public room');
        socket.broadcast.to('public').emit('server',socket.username + ' has connected to this room');    
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  socket.broadcast.to('public').emit('server',socket.username + ' has left the room');
  socket.leave(socket.room);
});

});
```

client side:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/public');
var user = Cookies.get('user');

socket.on('connect', function(){
 socket.emit('adduser', user); 
});

socket.on('server',function(msg){
    $('#conversation').append('<li> <b>Server: </b>'+msg+'</li>');
});
```

I am loading this client script in home component on dashboard/home, when  user moves to dashboard/contacts it does not disconnect. It also create duplicate socket listeners also because this client script will reloaded every time the component is loaded. 
starting state

[image: starting state]

move to contact routes:

[image]

Reloading home component

[image]

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Cause `disconnect` does work if used properly.

Comment: I have added my code, I think it will not auto disconnect.

Comment: @Abhinav Chauhan , i'm facing same issue , Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an Angular **service** for connecting and disconnecting. Call the service to Connect on the `ngOnInit` on the components you want and then call the disconnect method on the `ngOnDestroy` method.

You can also try to do the same implementing [Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Inside component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.chatService.connect()
 }

 ngOnDestroy(){
   this.chatService.disconnectSocket();
 }
```

Inside ChatService

```
    import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";
    
        private socket: Socket;
        
          constructor() {
            this.socket = io("http://localhost:4000");
          }

          connect(){
            this.socket.connect()
           }
        
           disconnectSocket(){
             this.socket.disconnect()
           }
```